# How to prove I am using too many connections towards Cloud MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-functions

I've got a situation where Google Cloud Functions querying Cloud MySQL often have to wait a long time to give back a response. When I look in Query Analyzer though, it seems those queries are actually quite fast.

I saw in another SO post that someone had a similar problem. The advice was not to connect from Cloud Functions to MySQL as it doesn't scale well, and the number of connections will max out.

But how do I prove that this is happening?

When I connected to the database and checked max connections it seemed like it was set to over 4000. But in other places I've read that at least the default config can only handle 150 or 200 connections, quite a difference.

How can I check number of connections used vs max? The connection queue length? Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the current setting for the limit of max connections with this query using any MySQL client:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
```

Check the current high-water mark for the greatest number of connections used since the last time MySQL Server was restarted:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';
```

If you got to the limit at any time in the past, you'll see `max_used_connections` as high as `max_connections`. It's also possible for it to get to `max_connections + 1`, because the super user can have one more connection even when the max is in use.

You can also watch:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_connected';
```

This number will rise and fall, it's the number of clients connected at the moment you run the command. Many sites have a monitoring tool that polls metrics like this one and graphs them over time.